# Get type from class name in Scala

Tags: scala, reflection

I want to do something like the following:

```
val factoryType = typeOf[Class.
          forName("com.menith.amw.worksheets." + params("problem") + "ProblemFactory")]
val factory = parse(params("args")).extract[factoryType]
```

The parse method allows me to obtain an instance of a case class by giving it a JSON string and I can then use the extract method by passing it the expected type. However I'm having some issues getting the type from Class.forName.

Comment: You are trying to mix two contradicting things - runtime reflection (`Class.forName`) and compile-time type reification (`typeOf`). You have to choose either world. If you don't know your type at compile-time, there is no way you can make `typeOf` work. In that case you must have a JSON deserializer that works without a static type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A great solution that might work would be to do polymorphic deserialization. This allows you to add a field (like "type") to your json and allow [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) (assuming you're using an awesome json parser like Jackson) to figure out the proper type on your behalf.

This [post](http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html) gives a great introduction to polymorphic types. It covers many useful cases including the case where you can't modify 3rd party code (here you add a Mixin to annotate the type hierarchy).

The simplest case ends up looking like this (and all of this works great with Scala objects too -- [jackson even has a great scala module](http://www.github.com/fasterxml/jackson-module-scala)):

```
object Test {
  @JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "type"
  )
  @JsonSubTypes(Array(
    new Type(value = classOf[Cat], name = "cat"),
    new Type(value = classOf[Dog], name = "dog")
  ))
  trait Animal

  case class Dog(name: String, breed: String, leash_color: String) extends Animal
  case class Cat(name: String, favorite_toy: String) extends Animal

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val objectMapper = new ObjectMapper with ScalaObjectMapper
    objectMapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

    val dogStr = """{"type": "dog", "name": "Spike", "breed": "mutt",  "leash_color": "red"}"""
    val catStr = """{"type": "cat", "name": "Fluffy", "favorite_toy": "spider ring"}"""

    val animal1 = objectMapper.readValue[Animal](dogStr)
    val animal2 = objectMapper.readValue[Animal](catStr)

    println(animal1)
    println(animal2)
  }
}
```

This generates this output:

```
// Dog(Spike,mutt,red)
// Cat(Fluffy,spider ring)
```

You can also avoid listing the subtype mapping, but it requires that the json "type" field is a bit more complex. Experiment with it; you might like it. Define Animal like this:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
  use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS,
  include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
  property = "type"
)
trait Animal
```

And it produces (and consumes) json like this:

```
/*
{
    "breed": "mutt",
    "leash_color": "red",
    "name": "Spike",
    "type": "classpath.to.Test$Dog"
}
{
    "favorite_toy": "spider ring",
    "name": "Fluffy",
    "type": "classpath.to.Test$Cat"
}
*/
```

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the deserialization code.

Comment: Done. A complete Scala example.