# Scala - Instantiate classes dynamically from a String

Tags: json, scala, reflection

I am trying to create a dynamic parser which allows me to parse json content into different classes depending on a class name.

I will get the json and the class name (as String) and I would like to do something like this:

```
val theCaseClassName = "com.ardlema.JDBCDataProviderProperties" 
val myCaseClass = Class.forName(theCaseClassName)
val jsonJdbcProperties = """{"url":"myUrl","userName":"theUser","password":"thePassword"}"""
val json = Json.parse(jsonJdbcProperties)
val value = Try(json.as[myClass])
```

The above code obviously does not compile because the json.as[] method tries to convert the node into a "T" (I have an implicit Reads[T] defined for my case class)

What would be the best way to get a proper "T" to pass in to the json.as[] method from the original String?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get type from class name in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26481797/get-type-from-class-name-in-scala)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A great solution that might work would be to do polymorphic deserialization. This allows you to add a field (like "type") to your json and allow [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) (assuming you're using an awesome json parser like Jackson) to figure out the proper type on your behalf. It looks like you might not be using Jackson; I promise it's worth using.

This [post](http://programmerbruce.blogspot.com/2011/05/deserialize-json-with-jackson-into.html) gives a great introduction to polymorphic types. It covers many useful cases including the case where you can't modify 3rd party code (here you add a Mixin to annotate the type hierarchy).

The simplest case ends up looking like this (and all of this works great with Scala objects too -- [jackson even has a great scala module](http://www.github.com/fasterxml/jackson-module-scala)):

```
object Test {
  @JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
    property = "type"
  )
  @JsonSubTypes(Array(
    new Type(value = classOf[Cat], name = "cat"),
    new Type(value = classOf[Dog], name = "dog")
  ))
  trait Animal

  case class Dog(name: String, breed: String, leash_color: String) extends Animal
  case class Cat(name: String, favorite_toy: String) extends Animal

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val objectMapper = new ObjectMapper with ScalaObjectMapper
    objectMapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

    val dogStr = """{"type": "dog", "name": "Spike", "breed": "mutt",  "leash_color": "red"}"""
    val catStr = """{"type": "cat", "name": "Fluffy", "favorite_toy": "spider ring"}"""

    val animal1 = objectMapper.readValue[Animal](dogStr)
    val animal2 = objectMapper.readValue[Animal](catStr)

    println(animal1)
    println(animal2)
  }
}
```

This generates this output:

```
// Dog(Spike,mutt,red)
// Cat(Fluffy,spider ring)
```

You can also avoid listing the subtype mapping, but it requires that the json "type" field is a bit more complex. Experiment with it; you might like it. Define Animal like this:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
  use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS,
  include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
  property = "type"
)
trait Animal
```

And it produces (and consumes) json like this:

```
/*
{
    "breed": "mutt",
    "leash_color": "red",
    "name": "Spike",
    "type": "classpath.to.Test$Dog"
}
{
    "favorite_toy": "spider ring",
    "name": "Fluffy",
    "type": "classpath.to.Test$Cat"
}
*/
```

Comment: That sounds really cool but I am using Play framework which contains a very powerful JSON library so I wouldn't like to include another dependency to an external library. Not sure if I can't do something like that with the Play json library though.

Comment: *cough *cough; clearly not all that powerful if it doesn't give you polymorphic deserialization. Looking at their API it doesn't seem possible to get an instance of Reads[T] from a classOf[T] or from a type token. I think the only option is the one that @lmm suggests if you're unwilling to use Jackson.

Comment: I've just given a try at your code and getting the following exception: Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.stratio.datavis.Test$Animal, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information
 at [Source: {"type": "dog", "name": "Spike", "breed": "mutt",  "leash_color": "red"}; line: 1, column: 1]
 at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:164)

Comment: @ardlema It sounds like you might be missing the `@JsonSubTypes` Mapping on the Animal trait. Which Animal trait are you using? I just copy/pasted the top block into a current project imported: `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation._` and  `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonSubTypes.Type` and it works just fine. I'm using Jackson 2.4.3.

Comment: Cool! Yes, it was my fault, I was not importing the proper classes. It is working now. I think I am going down this route. Thank you very much for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

You should select your `Reads[T]` based on the class name. Unfortunately this will probably have to be a manual pattern match:

```
val r: Reads[_] = theCaseClassName match {
  case "com.ardlema.JDBCDataProviderProperties" => JDBCReads
  case ... => ...
}
val value = json.as(r).asInstanceOf[...]
```

Alternately, look at the implementation of `json.as`; at some point it's probably requiring a `classTag` and then calling `.runtimeClass` on it. Assuming that's so, you can just do whatever it is and pass your own `myCaseClass` there.

Comment: Sounds good but I would like to avoid implementing a pattern matching with all the options (it will break my "dynamic" idea). I will have a look at the json.as implementation as you suggested.