# Is there an inverse of the function classOf[] in Scala?

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm trying to do something like

```
asInstanceOf[toClass("Person")]
```

is it possible to do implement such a function "toClass" in scala?

Edit: I need to use it in square brackets like the usage above, which requires a Class and not a type.

Background: Take a string I receive and convert the body of the request to a json object specified by that string.

Comment: This is impossible in a statically type-safe manner. You can do it with reflection, but you would lose all type-safety, which makes the entire thing pointless and you could just use `Any` to begin with.

Comment: I need it in conversion to Json in Play! framework, so any is not a good option at all. I need a string to become a Class for that to be put inside square brackets

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scala - get class from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268873/scala-get-class-from-a-string)

Comment: I would close it now - well I searched a lot but found nothing.

Comment: It doesn't work, actually @puhlen , I have to use it inside square brackes, as in as[Class] or validate[Class]

Comment: @puhlen: That would still just return a reflective proxy object *representing* the class, not the class itself. It *can't* return the class because types aren't objects in Scala, and methods can only return objects. What the OP wants just isn't possible. He needs a type and there is simply no way to produce a type from a method. Scala, like almost all statically-typed languages strictly separates the universe of types from the universe of values. Methods operate strictly on values.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Ah that make sense.

Comment: @puhlen can you remove the downvote..? (and duplicate flagging)

Comment: @JörgWMittag should I use enumerations then?

Comment: @LowFieldTheory apparently not unless the question is edited

Comment: editing to say what? my question is that.

Comment: @LowFieldTheory I mean that SO apparently prevents you from changing a vote on a question unless it has been edited

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Can you elaborate more? The background you provided isn't enough. If you can share some code it would be better.

Comment: Did you saw that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26719343/scala-instantiate-classes-dynamically-from-a-string?

Comment: @AndriyKuba I will try that, thanks. I think it's the same case of mine.